# Excel found unreadable content / Workbook cannot be opened or repaired

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I open an Excel file I get the following error message:

**Excel found unreadable content in *******.xls. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes**

Once I click yes I get the following error message:

**workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrrupt**

Eventually, I am not able to open the Excel file at all. It just stays blank. 
Is there anything that I can try to recover the file?

Comment: Did you have autosave switched on?

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, yeah it is switched on but even if I switch it off it does not work.

Comment: Try this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repairing-a-corrupted-workbook-7abfc44d-e9bf-4896-8899-bd10ef4d61ab?CorrelationId=1745287c-98ea-401b-851a-4450be666003&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010342840

Comment: Does not work either. It always goes back to the message "workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrrupt". Extract Data is also not possible.

Comment: Then it's looking like you'll have to go back to your last backup & re-do any work since then... better than having to do it all, at least :/

Answer (score 0):

See if Open Office can open it -
https://www.openoffice.org/download/

As strange as this suggestion sounds, people have made dramatic, emphatic claims that they were at the point of hopeless defeat in opening a file, until they tried this, and it opened. It may be worth the effort for you to try it.

Even then you may still have work to do to build a new workbook to get you to where you were before it went corrupt, but at least you can get to the data if this works, and hopefully formulas too, and ideally other aspects of file contents.

Make a copy first, of course, and do all your attempts to open it off a copy.

Corruption is a serious, serious problem though Microsoft has done almost nothing to help people deal with or even recognize it. Thus a strong backup strategy is even more incumbent with Excel files than with others. Keep in mind that just one generation of backup may not rescue you, because corruption is usually viciously silent, very much like cancer, and your latest seemingly good backup may be corrupt. Periodic non-overwritten backups (one per year, one per month, or whatever you decide) is one tactic of defense against the cancerous condition of corruption.